# Summation of value in dynamic element is not shown in all browser properly

Tags: php, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

the summation is shown in all browser correctly . Now when i delete row the value of summation will be decrease but in firefox browser does not show it correctly. Suppose 10 + 10 + 10 = 30 if delete 2 row then sum shows 20 . But this will be 10. What's going wrong.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("form").on('keyup', '.input_ttotal', function() {
            calculateSum();
        });

        $('#btnDel').click(function () {
            calculateSum();
        });

    });

    function calculateSum() {

        var sum = 0;

        $(".input_ttotal").each(function () {
            if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }
        });
        $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
    }
    </script>
```

Html is

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <div class="yes">
        <div id="cost1" class="clonedCost" style="display: inline;">
            <table border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label class="total" for="total">Total 1</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <input class="input_ttotal" id="ttotal" type="text" name="ttotal[]" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="addDelButtons_cost">
            <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="+">
            <input type="button" id="btnDel" value="-">
        </div>
        <p>Sum is:<span id="sum">0</span>
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

jsfiddle link is http://jsfiddle.net/ByLrz/1/

Comment: Can you post js code that handles, deleting row?

Comment: Just an FYI: your missing an opening <td> tag before your input

Comment: all js code given here.

Comment: @user1652747 the javascript in your jsfiddle does not conatin all the code in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `calculateSum();` is most likely being called before the element is removed. Try adding it in your delete confirm function in your `http://gestionale.odoyabooks.com/scripts/other_book_cost.js`

```
$('#btnDel').click(function () {

    if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to remove this section? This cannot be undone."))
        {
            var num = $('.clonedCost').length;

            $('#cost' + num).slideUp('slow', function () {$(this).remove(); 

            // after $(this).remove() recalculate
            calculateSum();

                if (num -1 === 1)
            $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', true);

            $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false).prop('value', "");});
        }
    return false;

    $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#btnDel').click(function () {
        calculateSum();
    });
```

All this does is call the calculateSum function, which in turn calculates the sum of all the values inside the `".input_ttotal"` inputs.

At no point are the inputs removed from the form, so the total sum will always be the same.

Comment: No total sum will not same all time. you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/ByLrz/1/ and run it in chrome browser. It work's fine but problem is firefox

Comment: I have ran it in firefox, chrome and IE and can't see any difference in behaviour? Your delete button has no functionality (apart from calling calculateSum() )

Comment: @Paddyd the js script to delete is in the External Resource tab - http://gestionale.odoyabooks.com/scripts/other_book_cost.js

Comment: @Sean Ah ok, I didn't see that. I'm not that familiar with jsfiddle, thanks.
Either way, it's still not deleting/adding rows....